# Finding a derivative using multiple chain rules

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Find the derivative of the function.
$y = [x + (x + \sin^2 x)^3]^4$

I know how to use the chain rule and I found the derivative to be:

$$4[x+(x+\sin^2(x))^3]^3 \cdot (1 + 3(x + \sin^2(x))^2) \cdot (1+\sin (2x))$$

but my online homework says that this is wrong. I can't figure what what I've done wrong and I've tried it several times now. Can somebody help?

Note: In the last term, I simplified $2\sin x\cos x$ to be $\sin(2x)$. I tried inputting both versions into my homework but it was wrong both ways.

Comment: The $1+\sin(2x)$ part should multiply the $3(x +\sin^2(x) )^2$ part, not the whole thing.

Comment: The $1+\sin (2x)$ term should be inside the previous group of parentheses.

Comment: The $1+\sin(2x)$ needs to be inside the 2nd set of parentheses.

Comment: Ah, I figured it must be a simple mistake like that. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\textbf{wrong:} \quad & 4[x+(x+\sin^2(x))^3]^3 \cdot \Big(1 + 3(x + \sin^2(x))^2\Big) \cdot (1+\sin (2x)) \\[10pt]
\textbf{right:} \quad & 4[x+(x+\sin^2(x))^3]^3 \cdot \Big(1 + 3(x + \sin^2(x))^2 \cdot(1+\sin (2x)) \Big)
\end{align}
The thing that gets multiplied by $1+\sin(2x)$ should be only $3(x+\sin^2 x)^2,$ not the sum of that and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to introduce some new functions to avoid messing up with the calculations.
Consider
$$
y=g^4(x)
$$
where
$$
g(x)=x+h^3(x) \quad\textrm{and }\ h(x)=x + \sin^2 x.
$$
Then
$$
y'=4g^3(x)g'(x)
$$
where 
$$
g'(x)=1+3h^2(x)\cdot h'(x)
$$
and
$$
h'(x)=1+2\sin x\cos x.
$$
Putting everything together you have the answer:
$$
y'=4g^3(x)\bigr(1+3h^2(x)\cdot (1+2\sin x\cos x)\bigr)
$$